# How to make buttons backcolor different from eachother

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How to make button2 Change its BackColor if its the same Color as in button1?

How does my program work? Well i have to press Start (button5) to mix my Colors, after that i press Check button to see the answer.

As you can see on the Picture, i have two green Buttons and two orange Buttons but  I dont want any of the button.backcolors to be equal. They all supposed to be different.

In another words, if button2.backcolor **is the same** as button1.backcolor, its supposed to mix its backcolor until it gets different. The only Colors that im allowed to use are Green,Red,Blue,Purple,Orange,Yellow

Any ideas how can i achieve this?

[image]

```
Random random = new Random();

List<Color> possibleColors = new List<Color>()
{
    Color.Red,
    Color.Green,
    Color.Orange,
    Color.Blue,
    Color.Purple,
    Color.Yellow,       
};

private Color GetRandomColorOfLoist()
{
    return possibleColors[random.Next(0, possibleColors.Count)];
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfLoist();
    button2.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfLoist();
    button3.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfLoist();
    button4.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfLoist();
    button1.Visible = false;
    button2.Visible = false;
    button3.Visible = false;
    button4.Visible = false;
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Visible = true;
    button2.Visible = true;
    button3.Visible = true;
    button4.Visible = true;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Arul Manivannans idea worked but after pressing on start and on check, if i press start again, the game simply crashes. My last question is, how can i hide start button (button5) after clicking on check button (button6)?

My code:

```
  Random random = new Random();

   List<Color> possibleColors = new List<Color>()
{
    Color.Red,
    Color.Green,
    Color.Orange,
    Color.Blue,
    Color.Purple,
    Color.Yellow,

    };


        private Color GetRandomColorOfLoist()
        {

            int index = random.Next(0, possibleColors.Count);
            Color ColorToReturn = possibleColors[index];
            possibleColors.Remove(possibleColors[index]);

            return ColorToReturn;



        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfLoist();
            button2.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfLoist();
            button3.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfLoist();
            button4.BackColor = GetRandomColorOfLoist();
            button1.Visible = false;
            button2.Visible = false;
            button3.Visible = false;
            button4.Visible = false;

            List<Color> possibleColors = new List<Color>()
{
    Color.Red,
    Color.Green,
    Color.Orange,
    Color.Blue,
    Color.Purple,
    Color.Yellow,


        };
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Visible = true;
            button2.Visible = true;
            button3.Visible = true;
            button4.Visible = true;

        }
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok, i got it. Thanks for help

Comment: Where is actually located `Random random = new Random();
` statement ? This is a well know behavior when spanning multiple Random object is a very small time lapse

Comment: the whole code i've posted is located in my form1.cs

Comment: where's precisely. Your code here does not compile. You can't have code out of a method. This precision is very important because of the behavior of random.

Comment: here is a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/PEmZGjt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to, not to have a repeated color, how about removing the color item from the list?

```
     private Color GetRandomColorOfLoist()
      {
        int index = random.Next(0, possibleColors.Count);
        Color ColorToReturn = possibleColors[index];
        possibleColors.Remove(possibleColors[index]);

        return ColorToReturn;
      }
```

Comment: Mastermind's rules allow a color to appear multiple times

Comment: Arul Manivannan . Your idea seems to work but the Problem is that when i click on start, then on check and on start again... the game crashes. Is there any way in which i could block  START button (button5) after checking so that the game doesnt Crash?

Comment: or how can i hide a START button after pressing on  check?

Comment: The game will surely crashes if you dint implement try catch on button (or any control) events. Seems you have fixed it, what was the change you made it. If the answer is helpful, can u mark it?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the Color returned from GetRandomColorOfLoist out of the possibleColors List. At start of button5_Click you have to refill the List of possible Colors again. Then it should work.

Comment: Mastermind's rules allow a color to appear multiple times

Comment: my teacher said that he doesnt want the Colors to appear multiple times